# Puppet 5.5.22, dnfmodule reset

Tags: puppet, rhel8, dnf

I've been trying to figure out how to convert

```
dnf module reset php
dnf module install php:remi-7.4
```

to a stanza in a puppet module for several hours without any success.

Has anyone figured out how to do that?  The doco on the puppet website is somewhat lacking, shall we say.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that reset isn't implemented with `dnf module` yet, just enable and disable, but it can be used as a package manager directly.

From a quick test on a CentOS 8 docker image this worked for me:

```
  package { 'dnf-utils':
    ensure      =>  present,
  }
  package { 'redhat-rpm-config':
    ensure      =>  present,
  }
  package { 'epel-release':
    ensure      =>  present,
    provider    =>  rpm,
    source      =>  'https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm',
    require     =>  Package['redhat-rpm-config']
  }
  package { 'remi-release':
    ensure      =>  present,
    provider    =>  rpm,
    source      =>  'https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm',
    require     =>  Package['epel-release']
  }
  exec { 'dnf-enable':
    path        =>  $path,
    command     =>  'dnf config-manager --enable remi remi-test remi-modular-test',
    require     =>  Package['remi-release']
    refreshonly =>  true,
  }
  exec { 'dnf-modules':
    path        =>  $path,
    command     =>  'dnf -y module reset php',
    require     =>  Exec['dnf-enable']
    refreshonly => true,
  }
  
  package { 'php':
    provider    => 'dnfmodule',
    ensure      =>  'remi-7.4',
  }
```

I think the repos could be refactored to `yumrepo` resources, but this is a good base to use `dnf module` with Puppet.

Comment: Thanks for this @PeterSouter - I'll give it a shot once I get to work.