# DNF Enable/Disable in Puppet

Tags: puppet, rhel8, dnf

I'm trying to get PHP 7.4 installed on my RHEL 8 system with Puppet, but can't get the package declaration right to disable php and enable php:7.4 with dnf.  The Puppet Package documentation doesn't describe well, and I wasn't able to learn anything from this post: [Puppet 5.5.22, dnfmodule reset](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063765/puppet-5-5-22-dnfmodule-reset/1063838#1063838?newreg=00ce085571e4434bbc9c90416f8e8ffa)

Right now, Puppet installs 7.2, and then these commands are run manually to upgrade.

```
dnf module disable php
dnf module enable php:7.4
dnf upgrade php
```

How do I do this all with puppet?

Answer (score 1):

[Puppet's resource package](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html) has the `provider` attribute, which accepts `dnfmodule` as a value. This way, you can enable and disable module streams easily:

```
  # Uninstall whatever eventual pre-enabled stream
  # Different title, and module name in "module" attribute,
  # only to avoid conflict with actual 'php' package
  package { 'php:module':
    ensure   => disabled,
    name     => 'php',
    provider => dnfmodule,      # Configs module, not package
  }
  package { 'php:7.4':          # Use resource title to choose stream
    ensure      => present,
    provider    => dnfmodule,
    enable_only => true,        # Don't install whole module
  }
  package {
    'php': ensure => present,   # From enabled 7.4 stream
  }
```

Confirm with:

```
dnf module list php
rpm -q php
```

Answer (score 0):

You could see if there is a module on the [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com), but failing that you can use `exec` resources with the `creates` argument (if the commands run create a specific file). Failing **that**, use the `exec` resource but tack on a `touch` command to create your own marker to keep the resource idempotent.

E.G:

```
exec {
  cmd => 'dnf module disable php && touch /etc/.dnf-php-disabled`
  creates => '/etc/.dnf-php-disabled'
}
```